# How to refresh Simple ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using below code ***to fetch folders from SD Card*** and also **deleting empty folders**

```
File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for (File inFile : files) {
        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
            // delete empty folder
            if (inFile.listFiles().length == 0) {
                inFile.delete();
            }
            // add names into an ArrayList and populate ListView.
            listingSDCard.add(inFile.getName());
        }
    }
```

but i don't know ***how to refresh listview***, because  i noticed that empty folder has been deleted programmatically from SD Card, but still visible into list, i am using simple list, i know **notifyDataSetChanged()** help us to refresh list.

my ***complete code:***

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAnimals);

    List<String> listingSDCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Church Application/";

    File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for (File inFile : files) {
        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
            // delete empty folder
            if (inFile.listFiles().length == 0) {
                inFile.delete();
            }
            // add names into an ArrayList and populate ListView.
            listingSDCard.add(inFile.getName());
        }
    }

     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this, 
                     R.layout.activity_archive_list,
                     listingSDCard);

     listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**Edited code:-**

```
 final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAnimals);       

    List<String> listingSDCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Church Application";

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             R.layout.activity_archive_list,
             listingSDCard);

    File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for (File inFile : files) {
        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
            // delete empty folder
            if (inFile.listFiles().length == 0) {
                inFile.delete();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            // add names into an ArrayList and populate ListView.
            listingSDCard.add(inFile.getName());
        }
    }

     listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

*Issue still not resolved* - still getting empty folder name into ListView, whereas folder not present in SD Card !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // delete empty folder
        if (inFile.listFiles().length == 0) {
            inFile.delete();
        } else {
            // add names into an ArrayList and populate ListView.
            listingSDCard.add(inFile.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Although you are deleting the folder in the system, you are adding it to your `listingSDCard`, you need to put it in an else.

Answer (score 0):

Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your Adapter.

code:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also you can use this:

```
arrayAdapter.invalidateViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

add this line after delete folder.